# Is the upper triangular matrix in function scipy.linalg.lu always in row echelon form?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra

I have a m x n matrix A, with n > m, and I am trying to identify independent rows by means of the row echelon form of it. Function scipy.linalg.lu returns a PLU factorization of my matrix, but U factor does not seem to be in echelon form, i.e., pivots are not in a staircase pattern. As far as I know, U factor should always be in a staircase pattern.

Consider the following example:

```
from numpy import array
from scipy.linalg import lu

A = array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
           [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
           [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
           [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

P, L, U = lu(A)
```

The U factor is not in row echelon form. For each row k, pivots should always be to the right of the pivot in row k-1. See that pivot in fifth row is not to the right of pivot in fourth row:

```
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0., -1., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1., -1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1., -1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Comment: Please provide sample code of an example.

Comment: En passant, I have already solved the problem of identifying independent rows through QR factorization, though my first try was to identify them by means of Gaussian elimination following Linear Algebra textbooks.

Comment: `scipy.linalg.lu` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lu.html) doesn't say `U` will be in row echelon form (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form).  It says it will be upper triangular (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UpperTriangularMatrix.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen the LUP decomposition before but I suspect it just doesn't do exactly what you think it does. I did the same decomposition in Matlab as you did above in Python and I got the exact same results you did. So I don't think it as problem with the Python LU function.

Update:
I have also implemented this in R (code below) and again the U matrix gives the same results as Matlab and Python. Unlike the others it gives the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In .local(x, ...) :
  Exact singularity detected during LU decomposition: U[i,i]=0, i=4.
```

Matlab:

Code:

```
A = ([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
           [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
           [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
           [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]);
[L,U,P] = lu(A);
U
```

Matlab results:
    U =

```
     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     0
     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     0     1
     0     0    -1    -1     0     0     0    -1    -1     0
     0     0     0     0     1    -1     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     1     1
```

Python Results (from your code):

```
U = 

array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0., -1., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1., -1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1., -1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

R:

Code:

```
library(Matrix)
A <- Matrix( c( 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 , 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1 , 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 , 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ),nrow=5,ncol=10,byrow=TRUE )
expand(mylu <-lu(A))
```

Results:

```
class "dtrMatrix" (unitriangular)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    .    .    .    .
[2,]    0    1    .    .    .
[3,]    1    0    1    .    .
[4,]    1    0    1    1    .
[5,]    1    0    1    0    1

$U
5 x 10 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    0    1    1    1    1     0
[2,]    0    1    0    1    1    0    1    0    0     1
[3,]    0    0   -1   -1    0    0    0   -1   -1     0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    1   -1    0    0    1     1
[5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    1     1

$P
5 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "pMatrix"

[1,] | . . . .
[2,] . . . | .
[3,] . . | . .
[4,] . | . . .
[5,] . . . . |
```

Comment: This is strange. The elements below the pivot in the fifth column should be zero, not 1, according to the following properties of the U factor (STRANG, 1988, p.72):

"(i) The nonzero rows come first - otherwise there would have been row exchanges - and pivots are the first nonzero entries in those rows.
(ii) Below each pivot is a column of zeros, obtained by elimination.
(iii) Each pivot lies to the right of the pivot in the row above. This produces the staircase pattern."

STRANG, G. Linear Algebra and its applications. 3rd Ed., Thomson, 1988.

Comment: In fact, the matrix I am applying the LU factorization to is much larger than the one given above in the example, and the U factor is far less in a staircase pattern than the above. My current hypothesis is that the rows in the U factor computed by the LU functions in both Python and Matlab are not properly ordered.

Comment: I just also did the factorization in R (see updated answer) and it too gave the same results.

Comment: The singularity warning given by R is meaningful only for square matrices. Rectangular matrices may well have zeros in diagonal positions after elimination. Unlike square matrices, zeros in the diagonal do not imply that the matrix is rank deficient or has no inverse. In fact, matrix A in the example is full rank.

Comment: It is interesting that if I cancel term U[5,5], by subtracting rows 4 and 5, I obtain the expected row echelon form, but then multiplying the factors PLU does not restore A. This seems to violate (iii) in Strang (1998, p.72). I think this has turned out to be more of a Linear Algebra question than a computational issue. I will post this question in Mathematics Exchange.

Comment: If you have three matrices C = A *B, I wouldn't think you could generally change B to B' and have C = A * B'. Since a row operation is a form of matrix multiplication, A * B' = A * D * B , unless D is special (i.e. identity) this wouldn't hold.

Comment: Sure. In LU decomposition, all row operations carried out on U are registered in L. The fact is that, when you cancel out element U[5,5] by means of subtracting row 5 from row 4, the corresponding element L[5,5] = 1 is not modified. This is why A = PLU turns to be false after this operation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that the LU decomposition will result in a U matrix in row echelon form.  It *may be* that the reason why it fails in this case is because the matrix is singular; I strongly suspect that is the reason, because one of the characteristics of a singular matrix is the absence of a complete set of pivots.

See the section on General Matrices at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition and the reference provided therein for specifics.